# Where is "Google APIs" for Android 1.6?

Tags: java, android, android-1.6-donut

I am going through the video tutorial at O'Reilly video training course "Developing Android Applications with Java" by Tony Hillerson. He mentioned that I must build my app against the "Google APIs" rather than the standard Android 1.6 API to use the Google Maps API for my app. I need this in order to import "com.google.android.maps.MapActivity" in my application class.

Problem is: I can't find this "Google APIs" anywhere under the latest Android SDK manager.

Where can I find this "Google APIs" for Android 1.6? Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Use SDK 2.1-update minimum. Personally, I use 2.2 most of the time, but 2.1-update will support pretty much every phone out there.

Comment: Why not 1.6, if the project does not require functionality beyond it?

Comment: Supporting extremely old versions of software is a bad habit. It leaves no incentive for people to upgrade. There are a lot of nice features in 3.0+ that devs never get to use because so many people are still stuck on 2.X, even. If everyone supported 3.0+, a lot of carriers would be far more likely to push the 3.0 update to their phones.

Comment: As of right now, in the last 2 weeks 2.9% of the devices that connected to the Market are 3.0+. In actuality what would happen if everyone built to 3.0+ right now, they would have very few users. 3.0 isn't made for phones. You'll start to see more and more phones that are 4.X soon. The carriers and the manufacturers move at their own pace, I don't feel like everyone building to 3.0 would put any more pressure on them. Also consider that the Market is not the only distribution channel in the world. There are still many 1.6 devices out there in the world that aren't hitting the Market.

Comment: That does not nullify any of my justifications for moving toward the future and not dwelling in older times. A great example of this is Apple. They move forward and support legacy software and hardware only to a certain point, forcing their users to upgrade. Look where it has gotten them. Look where it has gotten their OS. Look where it has gotten their mobile OS. Current statistics are irrelevant. What's relevant is the trend of progression and human nature.

Comment: As an independent developer, I try to make my app available to ALL devices, if possible. My income comes first, not Google's, Apple's or Microsoft's. If supporting 1.6 can get me more users, then supporting 1.6 is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install it from the ADT plugin from inside Eclipse or externally from SDK Manager
[image: Android SDK Manager]